# Ruby on Rails 7 Multistep form with multiple models logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently struggling with building up a multi step form where every step creates a model instance.

In this case I have 3 models:

1. UserPlan
2. Connection
3. GameDashboard

Since the association is like that:

An `user` has an `user_plan`
A `connection` belongs to an `user_plan`
A `game_dashboard` belongs to a `connection`

I would like to create a wizard to allow the current_user to create a game_dashboard going through a multi-step form where he is also creating connection and user_plan instance.

For this purpose I looked at Wicked gem and I started creating the logic from game_dashboard (which is the last). As soon as I had to face with form generating I felt like maybe starting from the bottom was not the better solution.

That’s why I am here to ask for help:

What would be the better way to implement this wizard? Starting from the bottom (game_dashboard) or starting
from the top (use_plan)?

Since I’m not asking help for code at the moment I didn’t write any controller’s  or model’s logic, in case it would be helpful to someone I will put it!

Thanks a lot

---

EDIT

Since i need to allow only one process at a time but allowing multiple processes, to avoid the params values i decided to create a new model called like "onboarding" where i handle steps states there, checking each time the step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to rely on the standard MVC pattern of Rails.

Just use the `create` and `update` controller methods to link to the next model's form (instead of to a `show` or `index` view)

E.g.

```rb
class UserPlansController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    if @user_plan = UserPlan.create(user_plan_params)
      # the next step in the form wizard process:
      redirect_to new_connection_path(user_id: current_user, user_plan_id: @user_plan.reload.id)
    else
      @user_plan = UserPlan.new(user: current_user)
      render :new
    end    
  end

  ...

  # something similar for #update action
end
```

---

For routes, you have two options:

### You could nest everything:

```rb
# routes.rb

resources :user do
  resources :user_plan do
    resources :connection do
      resources : game_dashboard
    end
  end
end
```

#### Pro:

This would make setting your associations in your controllers easier because all your routes would have what you need. E.g.:

`/users/:user_id/user_plans/:user_plan_id/connections/:connection_id/game_dashboards/:game_dashboard_id`

#### Con:

Your routes and link helpers would be very long and intense towards the "bottom". E.g.

`game_dashboard_connection_user_plan_user_path(:user_id, :user_plan_id, :connection_id, :game_dashboard)`

### You could just manually link your wizard "steps" together

#### Pro:

The URLs and helpers aren't so crazy. E.g.

`new_connection_path(user_plan_id: @user_plan.id)`

With one meaningful URL variable: `user_plan_id=1`, you can look up everything upstream. e.g.:

```rb
@user_plan = UserPlan.find(params['user_plan_id'])
@user = @user_plan.user
```

#### Con:

(not much of a "con" because you probably wind up doing this anyway)

If you need to display information about "parent" records, you have to perform model lookups in your controllers first:

```rb
class GameDashboardController < ApplicationController
  # e.g. URL: /game_dashboards/new?connection_id=1
  def new
    @connection = Connection.find(params['connection_id'])
    @user_plan = @connection.user_plan
    @user = @user_plan.user
    @game_dashboard = GameDashboard.new(connection: @connection)
  end
end
```

Comment: You could try to use shallow routes: `shallow: true` to make the routes less ugly while nesting. Personally, if there are ever any many-to-many in there, then you shouldn't nest, but otherwise it can be helpful

Comment: thanks @Chiperific The solution seems pretty good, i will try to follow the second way cause i already a namespace called "customer_area" so yeah, increasing the url path wouldn't be a good idea. I have two questions:
With your solution so i wouldn't need to use Wicked gem? 
What if an user closes the form while compiling? is there a way to save the state?

Comment: Also i had another idea but i don't know if this could be something really worth it: what about creating a new model called for example: onboarding, asking for inputs, saving those attributes as id where it's about association and text and after the onboarding model is created generate the three models (user_plan, connection, game_dashboard) based on onboarding instance just created?

Comment: The "state" would be saved at each step. When the user finishes filling out the `user_plan` form, the `user_plan` is immediately created, and so on. Creating a whole new model to capture everything is really unnecessary.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I would like to add:
since i won't allow to have concurrently more than 1 "wizard" running, could i avoid using url params to retrieve information? e.g:
`current_user` starts the wizard, he only compiles `user_plan` form. Then there's a redirect to  `connection` form. Here can i retrieve information for user_plan_id from the current_user ? Same for `game_dashboard` form: can i pass in the controller the `connection_id` from `current_user`? everything maybe handled by a flag that checks if the `current_user` has no on_going state (maybe an aasm state) user_plan ?

Comment: If a `user` only has one `user_plan`, which only has one `connection`, which only has one `game_dashboard`, then getting these objects without anything in the URL will be easy. If not, you could use the `session` to store IDs for each object during the wizard process.